# gmapping problem

Tags: navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear friends,

I have built a simple environment to carry out some tests in order to learn ros (new user).

I have built a urdf and using the appropriate launch I start the gazebo simulation

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
    <!-- this launch file corresponds to robot model in ros-pkg/robot_descriptions/pr2/erratic_defs/robots for full erratic -->
    <param name="/use_sim_time" value="true" />
    
    <!-- start up wg world -->
    <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(find simple_package)/worlds/MYROBOT.world"/>
    </include>
    
    <arg name="model" />
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(arg model)" />
    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" >
    </node>
    
    <!-- start robot state publisher -->
    <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen" >
        <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
    </node>
    <node name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -z 0.1 -model robot_model" respawn="false" output="screen" />
</launch>
```

In another terminal I send a recurring  cmd_vel like:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist  '{linear:  {x: 0.1, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}, angular: {x: 0.0,y: 0.0,z: 0.0}}'
```

and I can clearly see that the robot moves in the gazebo simulation.

The problem is when I try to execute the gmapping package.
In the terminal when I execute

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=/scan odom_frame:=/odom
```

I get either:

```
 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

or

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

a screenshot of my graph looks like:
[image: image description]

Do you have any idea what it goes wrong?

My ros version is indigo

Thanks in advance for your help

UPDATE.
I tried to follow the simple [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#download) and again I get

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
  what():  boost: mutex lock failed in pthread_mutex_lock: Invalid argument
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I downloaded the existing bag

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212790/gmapping-problem/) by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2015-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well after what I noticed in the tutorial (as I refer in the update) I performed a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and now is working fine.

---

Originally posted by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) with karma: 148 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ziwen Qin](https://answers.ros.org/users/26914/ziwen-qin/) on 2016-07-27**:
nice! Thank you